Grout still "wet" days after regrouting
Looking for a bit of a sanity check and make sure I'm not overthinking this.
We had issues with a crack in our grout and mold.  So we hired somebody to come and regrout the entire shower floor.  But the area that was cracked is still "wet". We called the company and they said that it was due to moisture trapped under the grout and would day weeks if not a month to dry out.  This is what I was trying to fix!  I imagine they should have removed the existing grout and let it air out, but they didn't.
Is it safe to let this dry out over weeks or should I have them come out, remove the affected grout and wait a day or two for it to dry out?

